# Setting HttpClient POST Request body without "="

Tags: java, post, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to make POST request with body like this:

```
{"a":[12345]}
```

If I try to build POST requests like this:

```
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("{\"u\":[123]}", ""));
httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
```

it, of course, makes a POST request body with a "=" delimeter

```
{"a":[12345]}=
```

How do I make it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using StringEntity,  created with your JSON payload,  instead of your current use of UrlEncodedFormEntity, NameValuePair et al.